# .vspscc file in .NET Standard / Core

Tags: .net, visual-studio, asp.net-core, tfs, configuration-files

How to handle .vspscc files in .NET Standard / .NET Core?

Should they still be part of the project?

Should they be under source control (checked in)?

-> If not, should it better be excluded in SourceControl Explorer explicit or with a .tfignore File

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assume you are using TFVC as your source control.

> `.vspscc` is a **Source Code Control (SCC) file** for projects created
>   with Microsoft Visual Studio; contains metadata used for tracking
>   revisions of Visual Studio software development projects; includes
>   information such as the version number, file path, and the number of
>   nested projects.

You do not need to handle/modify/track these files. VS automatically exclude these files, prevent them be checked in source control.

There will be a  `<Exclusion>*.vspscc</Exclusion>` session in the *LocalItemExclusions.config* file. [What files are ignored in TFS by default?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43224302/what-files-are-ignored-in-tfs-by-default?rq=1)

If these files got some issue, the issue may related to source control binding. Simply unbind and rebind the source control may do the trick.

If you are using Git as your source control. They're completely useless.

More detail about this file, you could also take a look at this question: [Why does Visual Studio check out the .vspscc file when I add a file to a project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3120749/why-does-visual-studio-check-out-the-vspscc-file-when-i-add-a-file-to-a-project)

Comment: I tried both scenarios (under/not under source control). When the file is not under source control I got an error:

Project Properties -> Debug -> Change Something -> Save


"Check Out. The Item '...vspscc' could not be found in your workspace, or you do not have permission to access it."

When it is under source control it works - but anyway there are no changes in the file.

Comment: @sampa Thanks for your kindly sharing.  You could just ignore these files, there are useless. No need to track any changes.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need this file.  It's for TFVC.  Has you can see it's in the gitignore file 
[Git Ignore File sample](https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/VisualStudio.gitignore)